# Why can't I update iMovie?

Tags: mac-appstore, imovie

I tried to update iMovie and got the following error.

> Update Unavailable with This Apple ID
>
> This update is not available for this Apple ID either because it was bought by a different user or the item was refunded or cancelled.

It is true that I have not purchased it, indeed I don't think I have ever used it. It came with my MacBook Pro when I bought it in 2011. I mainly decided to install to stop the App Store from nagging me about it.

EDIT
After a number of calls to Apple Support, and a solution which didn't work I was given a redemption code to install the new version.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes. The app has Modified date Friday, 11 February 2011 12:48 am and the Mac was delivered 18 March

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're running a system prior to OS X 10.9, you might consider updating it. Upgrading Apple's iApps from the 2011 versions to the 2013 versions requires either Mavericks (for version 10.0.5) or Yosemite (v10.0.6). The boilerplate message from the App Store has misled a good number of people.

If, on the other hand, you *are* using 10.9 or 10.10, first check the "Purchases" page of the App Store (Fourth icon across on the top of the toolbar) to see if the iApps are available for download. These versions replace--not upgrade--pre-installed iApps with bundles which tie them to a combination of your Apple ID and your computer's hardware ID.

If such isn't the case, contact [Apple Support for Mac Apps](https://getsupport.apple.com/Issues.action), and explain your situation. You are entitled to an upgrade.

Comment: Excellent response. Check the default google search and advice was really random. Found this answer (regarding OS X 10.10) to be spot on. You sir are a gentlemen and a scholar.

Answer (score 1):

I logged out of iTunes account - I then moved IMovie to the Trash and emptied trash.
I then went to the App store and went to 'buy' iMovie at the latest version, it then asked for my itunes password.  After entering password it said it would be free as I already had iMovie previously.
20 minutes later after a download, I opened up iMovie and hey-presto, it has been updated and ITunes is available.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a new Mac I just purchased. Turns out the fix was just to go to the Profile tab in the App Store, click accept on the top, and verify your passcode. After that try updating!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Only ever had one Apple ID, and was logged in with it. Turned out to be a very simple issue for me -- I don't purchase from the App Store, so I'd forgotten that they required a credit card when I set up my new Mac. That card had expired recently and I'd forgotten to update it on my Apple account.