# Update unavailable with this Apple ID?

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-id, photos.app, software-update

I recently updated to OS X 10.11, El Capitan. After the update one `iPhoto (Version 9.6.1, Released Mar 20, 2015)` update from the App Store is not getting installed. It shows:

> Update unavailable with this appleID
>
> This update is not available for this Apple ID either because it was bought by a different user or the item was refunded or cancelled.

If this particular update is not available, How to remove the `1 Update available` message from `AppStore` and the red badge from `AppStore` dock icon.

Comment: Approaches in this similar question may help, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154793/why-cant-i-update-imovie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 Methods…

1. Sign out of the App Store then back in using the correct credentials for the iPhotos download, or
2. Delete iPhoto & use Photos instead, which is iPhoto's replacement.

Comment: 3. For an older account go to your purchases and click 'Adopt' for some of the Apple apps that are now free that come pre-installed on new Macs

Answer (score 0):

Does iPhoto show up under `Purchased` tab of your `App Store`? If yes, you can try deleting the app from **/Applications** and try installing (downloading) it again from `Purchased` tab.

Comment: `iPhoto` is not listed under `Purchased` tab

Answer (score 0):

In case you have never started it before, start, and then close the application. This worked for me to update GarageBand on a new computer: An update was recommended by the App Store application, but I couldn't install it (I got the above message). Then I started GarageBand, closed it, and then I could update.